# Second Generation Packages: ERROR running force:package:version:create: : The object 'Object' of type Settings metadata does not exist

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, 2gp, second-generation-packaging

I am getting this error when I create version of a new second generation managed package. The project has simple Apex class without code and dependency on single 1st generation managed package.

Are the any workaround for the error e.g. specifying some settings to `project-scratch-def.json`?

Apex Class:

```
public with sharing class MyApexClass {

}
```

sfdx-project.json (Ids, package name, alias, dependent package name, and version are changed):

```
{
    "packageDirectories": [
        {
            "path": "force-app",
            "default": true,
            "package": "my package name",
            "versionName": "ver 0.1",
            "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
            "dependencies": [
                {
                    "package": "otherManagedPackage@1.0.1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "name": "my project name",
    "namespace": "mynamespace",
    "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
    "sourceApiVersion": "52.0",
    "packageAliases": {
        "my package name": "0Hoxxx",
        "otherManagedPackage@1.0.1": "04txxxxx"
    }
}
```

Comment: If there's a dependency on another package, have you declared that in the sfdx-project.json? I suggest you [edit] your question to include detail of the Apex class and the sfdx-project.json. Without more info it's possible you won't get an answer.

Comment: @PhilW Yes, I have declared the dependency. I have added code snippets with the Apex class and sfdx-project.json

Answer (score 2):

I have found the reason of the issue. It failed because of broken project-scratch-org-def.json file.

I have added `objectSettings` section to `settings`

```
{
  "orgName": "MyCompany",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": [],
  "settings": {
    "objectSettings": {
       "account": {
          "defaultRecordType": "default"
       }
    }
  }
}
```

instead of adding it to the root https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file.htm

```
{
  "orgName": "MyCompany",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": [],
  "objectSettings": {    
     "account": {
        "defaultRecordType": "default"
     }
  }
}
```